# Correspond panda DataFrame values to a key of rgb color values based on value within the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key

I have a very large dataframe of about 15000 rows and 500 columns. I wish to look at each individual value within the dataframe and associate that to a specific color based on dictionary key containing rgb values. I then wish to plot the rgb values using matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you want to do. Here is a good framework.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']})
myColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']  # replace with hexes
data = []
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    # conditions
    data.append('red')
df['color'] = data
```

Code yields:

```
   column color
0   apple   red
1  banana   red
2  cherry   red
```

Comment: Im trying to create a key that will look at the value and say ooh this value according to the dictionary corresponds to this color and then appends that to a new dataframe

Comment: Then instead of `data.append('red')`  use `data.append(dict[key])`